# Magento Dev - how to ensure real customers/vendors do not receive email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, notification

Would like to ask your opinion - I have a `Dev/Testing` Server which consists of real `vendors/customers data`. How can I ensure no real `customers/vendors`  would receive any **testing email** e.g. low stock notification, order confirmation, etc.

Magento version. 1.9.2.4

Comment: Main intention is to ensure that data is dummy or at least not used for sending out emails..... hope anyone can assist :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dev/testing data should be anonymized before imported into it to avoid leaking real customer data and also sending emails/notifications to any customers.

There are few tools that are helping do that without much hassle but you could also write a simple module based on `Faker` library.

From what I've tested and works:

- https://github.com/integer-net/Anonymizer
- https://github.com/kalenjordan/magerun-addons
- https://github.com/SchumacherFM/Anonygento

You can also dump the data stripped for development - without any customer/sales data - from live database with n98-magerun command:

```
n98 db:dump --strip=@development
```

What above command does it takes care of all tables that shouldn't be moved to a development environment therefore all email queues etc are also purged.

Another solution is to implement a MailCatcher on your dev machine and configure Magento to use it instead of a production email config.
This could be easily done with LimeSoda_EnvironmentConfiguration but as I've stated earlier - no real customers data should be exposed on dev environment.

Comment: @jesterxxx Please also note that not using real (= identifiable) customer data on test systems is a legal requirement in many jurisdictions (e.g. european union), so it is a good idea anyways, even if you are not sending any mails at all.

Comment: Very important comment from @PaŭloEbermann ^ Consider upvoting it.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann - Thanks for your advice. Noted.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through backend side.

Just go to `System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings`. There set `Yes` to `Disable Email Communications` option. This will prevent all email which are going through your application.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Rajeev, thanks for your reply!. 
By doing so - i still want emails to be sent to my own email address to see how is the mail notification like. 

Is there a way i can ensure all the vendor's/ customer's data is dummy instead?

Comment: to do that, probably you need to write some custom code atleast. There is no default option to achieve that.

Comment: You can check emails wether with the tool provided under system > transactional emails. If you edit them directly in the source, you can add header and footer to the body to see how they look like.

Comment: Hi Christophe - thanks for your reply. but it seems not what i was looking for :)

Comment: also checkout what @versedi suggested. That looks like some awesome tools.